# How do I know what type of hard drive interface my laptop uses?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a Toshiba Satelite L50-B-1LN, and I want to upgrade the hard drive to a SSD. However, I do not know what type of SSD to buy. I need to know if my laptop uses SATA 2, SATA 3, IDE, etc. How do I find out?

**Edit:**

Here is a picture of the HDD and port. Can anybody confirm if this is SATA?

[image]

Comment: Simplest method would be to look at the label on the drive itself.

Comment: Search for a manual at [Toshiba](http://bit.ly/1ItylKc). You'll see that your model isn't listed. The closest I've found was a `Satellite Pro L50-A` where the manual states it's "SATA". You could search for reviews or shops who still lists your exact Laptop model. But most of them don't go into detail enough. You could [search on youtube to find an open Toshiba Satellite Pro L50-B](https://youtu.be/YatNrUHN3c4?t=172) (the -1LN is missing!). You will see a SATA connector and a HDD label which reads `MQ01ABD075`. [According to Amazon](http://amzn.to/1WZXyaa), this is indeed a SATA 3.0 drive

Comment: @ramhound I opened it up and took a few pictures but there is nothing that identifies it as SATA 2 or SATA 3

Comment: @Blue7 - SATA 2 vs SATA 3 does not matter.  SATA functionality of your device is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Open device manager, expand disk drive, you can see the model of your hard drive and the type of connection, for sure write down the model and search on google the hard drive model specification, you will find whether the original hard drive is IDE, SATA, SATA 2 or SATA 3 from the specification of the original hard drive.

Comment: The hard drive itself is SATA 2.0. I used hardware identifying software to check this. However the port /interface into the motherboard could still be SATA 3.0 couldn't it? In that case it would be best for me to upgrade to a 3.0 hard drive.

Comment: @Blue7 - Unlikely.  So purchase a SATA 3 device, it will work, even if you have a SATA 2 port.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is SATA.

You can use any SATA SSD.

For more general reference, practically all laptops made after 2006 have SATA. SATA versions are all backwards and forwards compatible (barring specific buggy devices) and have no real limitations below 2TiB.

SATA 6Gbps drives will work slower in a SATA 3Gbps port but the difference will not be noticeable in normal day-to-day use.

http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i,-sata-ii-and-sata-iii

Comment: Well, but size limitations can significantly restrict what drives you can put into a laptop.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: What size limitations?

Comment: Many laptops won't take full-sized desktop hard drives, for example. I'm not sure what the specific size restrictions are for this particular laptop, but I'm not necessarily sure _all_ SATA SSD's would necessarily fit.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: Practically **all** laptops won't take desktop HDDs but I'm not sure how that's relevant. SSDs are not full size desktop hard drives. All consumer SSDs will necessarily fit any laptop that has a slot for a hard drive.

Comment: Many laptops take 1.8" drives (spinning, or SSD) only, but you can buy 2.5" or (much more rarely) 3.5" SSD's.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: Replace "many" with "virtually none since 2011" and you'd be right. Not to mention 1.8" drives use a micro-SATA connector, not SATA.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I've just measured it. It is [3.875 inch long](http://i.imgur.com/70V288F.png) by [2.688 inch wide](http://i.imgur.com/ZFgA5jJ.png). Should I buy 2.5"?